# Why is my small DC motor so weak with this N-type MOSFET in this simple circuit and 9V battery?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, dc-motor

Here is my simple circuit. Any help is appreciated:

[image]

When I press the momentary switch, the motor spins but it is very weak. I'm trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

When I connect it directly, it spins with a lot more power. Also, my multimeter is doing weird things when I try to measure the current.
When measuring current in the 'mA' setting on my multimeter, the reading is 0.82 mA and the motor does not turn.

When measuring current in the '10A' setting on my multimeter, the reading is 0.052 A and the motor spins.

Comment: Try moving the switch to the low side, not the high side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why load in NPN transistor switch are located in collector circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219324/why-load-in-npn-transistor-switch-are-located-in-collector-circuit) The other question has a BJT while yours is a MOSFET, but the answer is the same.

Comment: Put the motor connection between the supply and the D with the S to GND. Or use a P-channel mosfet. Or use a N-channel with a isolated gate driver.

Comment: how are you measuring the current?

Comment: I am measuring current by breaking the circuit between the FET and motor and inserting multimeter inline that circuit. Not sure why the readings are so different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other people have already commented, switch the motor with the transistor in the circuit. When using a transistor to drive a load fully-on or fully-off, you want \$V_{GS}\$ to be independent of the current driving the load. In your layout, \$V_{GS}\$ will decrease as the motor gains angular velocity due to the back EMF generated by the motor, which will rapidly decrease the transistor's conductance, "starving" the motor of current. Eventually, the motor will settle at a speed much lower than the rated no-load speed.

Comment: By transistor I mean a MOSFET, specifically

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say Vgs, are you placing Source 'under' (based on my circuit image) the transistor by the motor, or above the transistor by the V supply.

Comment: The source terminal is the one connected to the motor in your schematic